# Changing the background of a sub-menu

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website page and I would like to change the sub menu's back ground color to match the main menus. Currently my code looks like this.

```
<style>
div.main-content{
            width:160px;
            height:500px;
            margin:20px 10px;
            background-color:#000000;
            border:1px solid black;
            opacity:.6;
        }
        div.menu-header{
            margin:0px 0px;
            font-family:"sans-serif", Gadget, sans-serif;
            font-size:20px; 
            color:#ffffff; 
            padding: 10px;
        }

        a {
            color: inherit;
            text-decoration: inherit;
        }

        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
        }

        nav ul ul {
            display: none;
        }

            nav ul li:hover > ul {
            display:block;
            position:relative; left: 160px;
            }

        .menu-header ul{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 185px;
            list-style-type: none
        }

        div.sub-menu {
           width:160px;
            height:500px;
            margin:20px 10px;
            background-color:#000000;
            border:1px solid black;
            opacity:.6;
        }

</style>

<nav id="access" role="navigation">
<div class="menu-header">
    <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
        <li>
            About
            <ul>
                <div class="sub-menu">
                <li>Link 1</li>
                <li>Link 2</li>
                <li>Link 3</li>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            Contact
            <ul>
                <div class="sub-menu">
                <li>Link</li>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

I googled and tried some of the solutions but it didn't change anything. I even tried to make another class to address the sub menu (as I did above in the code) and it's not working. Can someone please explain to me what's wrong and how I can fix this? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: your code showing that you have change the background color of sub menu... here is the fiddle file of your code, I have just added the background color in li

Comment: can you please explain what you like to achieve... any screen shot will be helpful

Comment: `<div>` is not allowed in `<ul>`, only `<li>`.

Comment: Here's the whole code. http://pastebin.com/kQTurUtP

Comment: @ IkoTikashi you are right, this is updated fiddle file  http://jsfiddle.net/v8okkn2x/3/

Comment: I ran it in my editor bracket and the sub menu colors isn't the black with opacity of 0.6. So that's why I think my attempt to change the submenu color failed.

Comment: @ Exilius please check this http://jsfiddle.net/v8okkn2x/3/.   you need to update your code because div is not allowed inside ul. Also submenu background color is working here.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! Sorry I didn't check the updated comments in time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want the same background color on the main and sub menu?

Btw. there is nothing in your code that refers to the `main-content`

```css
div.main-content {
    width:160px;
    height:500px;
    margin:20px 10px;
    background-color:#000000;
    border:1px solid black;
    opacity:.6;
}
div.menu-header {
    margin:0px 0px;
    font-family:"sans-serif", Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#ffffff;
    padding: 10px;
}
a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: inherit;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    left: 175px;
}
.menu-header ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 185px;
    list-style-type: none
}
div.sub-menu {
    width:160px;
    height:500px;
    margin:20px 10px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .6);
    border:1px solid black;
}
#access {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.menu-header {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.menu {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .6);
}
```

```html
<nav id="access" role="navigation">
    <div class="menu-header">
        <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
            <li>About
                <ul>
                    <div class="sub-menu">
                        <li>Link 1</li>
                        <li>Link 2</li>
                        <li>Link 3</li>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Contact
                <ul>
                    <div class="sub-menu">
                        <li>Link</li>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```